# YUI source directory filter

Tags: javascript, maven-2, yui, maven, compression

I am using YUI maven plugin and I want to know how to compress a specific directory and exclude all others.

In maven I declare src/main/webapp/javascript to get all .js files in this directory but in the output directory all js of application in this directory appear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [usage page](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/usage_compress.html). It contains instructions on how to accomplish such tasks.

Here's your scenario:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compress</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>        
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <!-- add excludes here -->
      <exclude>**/*.pack.js</exclude>
      <exclude>**/compressed.css</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

There is no `includes` parameter, so you can't specify only one directory and have all others excluded. However, you can achieve the same functionality by combining the [outputDirectory](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/compress-mojo.html#outputDirectory) and [sourceDirectory](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/compress-mojo.html#sourceDirectory) parameters.

```
<configuration>
    <!-- select only the directory you want to compress -->
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/javascript/yourSubDir
    </sourceDirectory>
    <!-- and send it to the right output directory -->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/yourSubDir
    </outputDirectory>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @user543656 always glad to help, but if you think the answer ios correct you should accept it and if you like it you may also upvote it